# Can a Gentile and Noahaide put a prayer note in the kotel

Tags: halacha, tefilla, shlichus-agency, kotel-western-wall

Can a Jew put a prayer note for Hashem on behalf of a gentile Noahide in the spaces of cracks of the Kotel, if that gentile is unable to go to Israel to do it himself?  I know that any legitimate prayers are accepted near the wall by Hashem.  Can this type of prayer note be kept in the Kotel slit on behalf of me by anybody -- does halacha allow this?

Comment: yes and but for a goy we use the father's name instead of the mother's name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.**

Kings I chapter 8, 41-43
http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt09a08.htm

41 Moreover concerning the stranger that is not of Thy people Israel, when he shall come out of a far country for Thy name's sake--

42 for they shall hear of Thy great name, and of Thy mighty hand, and of Thine outstretched arm--when he shall come and pray toward this house;

43 hear Thou in heaven Thy dwelling-place, and do according to all that the stranger calleth to Thee for; that all the peoples of the earth may know Thy name, to fear Thee, as doth Thy people Israel, and that they may know that Thy name is called upon this house which I have built.

Comment: There are not actually any halachic rules about placing notes in the Kotel, not for Jews, and not for anyone else. These verses seem to be a prayer that the non-jew will be answered at this place just as a Jew should be answered. As far as notes go, that should also be the same.

Comment: at Ariel k & Binyamin, thanks for the well studied quotes and your answer.